# What does "人の入れた曲にしかも小声で座ったまま!" mean?

Tags: grammar, sentence

[image]

I can understand the sentence from "しかも" onwards, but the former part is quite confusing to me. In particular:

- Who does "人" refer to?
- Does "入れた" here mean "insert", like choosing the song to sing to?
- Why is "に" used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**人**
is used to refer to the speaker himself. (In the scene, it is Madarame) It literally means "other person", from the perspective of the listener, hence the speaker himself.

Other examples might help:

1. 人の言うことを聞け : Listen to what I say! = Listen to me.
2. よく人にそんなこと言えるな : How dare you say such a thing to me.

Note that 人 can be really *other* - that is, a third person: The first of the above can also mean *Listen to him/others*.

**入れた** means just *put*. The standard verb to set a song in Karaoke (カラオケで曲を入れる) . You can think it as inserting the song into the list of songs to be played.

**に** might be a little irregular here, but a natural possibility is 人の入れた曲**に合わせて**.

歌うな is obviously omitted at the end of the phrase, so the whole phrase is like

- *(Don't sing) in tune with the song I set, and that in a tiny voice, and without standing(, and in bass)!*

(I'm not sure how to properly phrase this, but hopefully you see what I mean).